# ionic capacitor IOS: play audio in the background without stopping previously playing audio from other apps

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

In my angular ionic capacitor app, **on IOS** when I play Spotify-Music in the background and then my quiz-app makes a sound, then the spotify music will stop playing.

this is happening with both:

HTMLAudioElement
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement

and
capacitor-community/native-audio
(source: https://github.com/capacitor-community/native-audio/issues/40)

Does anyone have a fix to make this work?

Note: it works in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just solved this issue myself by using this package: https://github.com/Cap-go/native-audio

This fork is ahead of the package you have mentioned and is able to mix audio. Check out the fade and focus options mentioned in the readme.

Comment: I am not really satisfied with this plugin. Somehow the audio sounds really off sometimes, too quiet & distorted. And also sometimes it is very delayed, after a click, or does not sound at all after a click. (my buttons make sounds)

Did you experience similar things? Cause maybe I just did a wrong setup, not sure.

Comment: This plugin is probably still the best audio solution out of all the audio plugins I have tried